# I asked a word question that has run away with me?

Tags: discussion, support, asking-questions, specific-question, challenges

[Easiest WordSearch](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/176443/easiest-wordsearch?noredirect=1#comment424869_176443)

I've asked a crossword related question thats been on my mind for quite a while. I've made various edits from suggestions in the comments. I don't think I can adjust the question myself to the point of getting it reopened or that me addressing more individual points is going to result in making progress with it rather than going in circles. I'm asking for some more hands on edit request assistance to change the wording and rules.

Right now similar questions risk being closed as duplicates because of this question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First off:  **I don't think the challenge is off-topic.  It is a bit unclear, and the scoring doesn't lead to interesting submissions, but it *is* on topic.**  Accordingly, I've voted to reopen.

Now, I *do* have some suggestions for improvement:

1. The word "easiest" is misleading here.  On my first read, I assumed that we were scored based on how easy the crossword was.  I'd definitely remove it from the post (and optionally remove it from the title).
2. Competitive submissions aren't going to calculate the word search on the fly.  Rather, they will output a precalculated wordsearch.  You can fix this in several ways:  Having multiple grid sizes, having multiple word sets, or various other options.

Finally, I'd like to mention that if a challenge is closed, we generally avoid it as a duplicate target.  So, if there was a well-defined challenge that was a duplicate of a poorly-defined challenge, we won't dupe the well-defined challenge.

Comment: Thank you, I've edited accordingly. What do you think of using a dictionary that is divided into reading levels and putting an upper bound on the reading level? The currently dictionary looked good but I've since found contains an overwhelmingly large amount of nonsense words.

Comment: I see somone else fell for this NGram dictionary in there question too :-/